# Joining 2 lists of objects based on object id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In my web application I am fetching 2 lists of objects from database.

First list of objects **Employee**

```
1 
  Name: Tom
  Week1: 1
  Week2: 3
  Week3: 7
2 
  Name: Mike
  Week1: 2
  Week2: 1
  Week3: 7
```

Second list of objects **listOfId**

```
1
  id: 1
  color: green
  symbol: AT
2
  id: 2
  color: red
  symbol: TB
3 
  id: 3
  color: blue
  symbol: TD
```

I would like to be able now to display it in a form of table, where for each of the weeks, I display this weeks color and symbol (each week matched on Employee.Week# = listOfId.id)

Something like this

```
Name | Week1 | Week1 Color | Week1 Symbol | Week2 | Week 2 Color etc...
Tom      1       green           AT           3         blue
Mike     2       red             TB           1         green
```

In total I will have constant 20 weeks for each employee.

I considered writing a SQL query which would take in week id, and return color and symbol. But for 50 people * 20 weeks... I would need to run this query 1000 times.

I am looking for better approach to solving this issue

my Models:

```
 public class WeekViewModel
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string ShortNAme { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Color { get; set; }
    }
}


public class EmployeeWeekViewModel
{
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
   public int week1 { get; set; }
    public int week2 { get; set; }
    public int week3 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: is your question about how to join the 2 lists after querying the DB, or how to make a single DB query ?

Comment: what is the best approach to join those two list of objects in to one, but to do this for each of the weeks. Possibly within the application and not SQL

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your correct, you have two lists coming from DB:

- `employeesList` which represents the employees with their corresponding weeks `ID`
- `weeksList` which represents the weeks for an employee.

Now, you want to join these two lists to display the information in a **simple** table format. I would do something like that:

```
public class EmployeeWeekViewModel{
  public string EmployeeName{get;set;}
  public WeekViewModel Week1 {get;set;}
  public WeekViewModel Week2 {get;set;}
  ...
  public WeekViewModel Week20 {get;set;}
}

public class WeekViewModel{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Color{get;set;}
  public string Symbol{get;set;}
}

employeesList.Select(t=> new EmployeeWeekViewModel(){
  EmployeeName = t.Name,
  Week1 = weeksList.FirstOrDefault(w => w.id == t.Week1).Select(w => new WeekViewModel(){
    Id = w.id,
    Color = w.color,
    Symbol = w.symbol
  }),
  Week2 = weeksList.FirstOrDefault(w => w.id == t.Week2).Select(w => new WeekViewModel(){
    Id = w.id,
    Color = w.color,
    Symbol = w.symbol
  }),
  ...
});
```

In order to not make a request for each week, I would suggest send to you query a list of week Ids to get them once ([checkout this example](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-in)).

Comment: Partially that is what i have been looking for. but i am having a bit of a problem with comparing the values....(w => w.id == t.Week1) states that it cannot compare int to WeekViewModel :(

Comment: `t.Week1`, stands for `Week1` property in the object you get from DB

Comment: thanks, but i still don't get it. I have added my models to the question. Week1 etc are of type int, which is returned from db.

Comment: my point is to define another `EmployeeViewModel` that have `Weeks` as `WeekViewModel` not as `int` properties.